# Deleting a ServingUrl created from a GcsFilename instead of a BlobKey doesn't seem to be supported?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am porting my Google App Engine app from the BlobStore to the Google Cloud Store.

I found that in GAE SDK 1.9.7 they deprecated all the `.getServingURL()` methods that took `BlobKey` and replaced them with on that takes a `ServingUrlOptions` object as configuration.

This make sense and seems to work, but there doesn't seem to be any matching `.deleteServingUrl()` that takes a `GcsFilename`?

I found the following in the SdkReleaseNotes but it doesn't clarify how you actually do this?

> Version 1.7.0 - June 26, 2012
>
> - You can now use get_serving_url() and delete_serving_url() for Google Cloud Storage buckets.

There is nothing in the `ImagesService` [javadoc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/images/ImagesService) that appears to do the job.

#### How do you delete a serving url that is created with a GcsFilename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

After way too much digging through JavaDocs, I discovered:

[`BlobKey createGsBlobKey(java.lang.String filename)`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreService#createGsBlobKey(java.lang.String))

### Here is the complete solution I ended up with.

#### Imports:

```java
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobKey;
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesService;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceFactory;
import com.googlecode.objectify.Work;
import com.vertigrated.gae.codex.service.datastore.entity.ImageMetadata;

import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import java.util.UUID;

import static com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.ofy;
```

#### And the code:

```java
private static final BlobstoreService BLOBSTORE_SERVICE;
private static final ImagesService IMAGES_SERVICE;

static
{
    BLOBSTORE_SERVICE = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    IMAGES_SERVICE = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();
}

@Override
public boolean delete(@Nonnull final UUID uuid)
{
    return ofy().transact(new Work<Boolean>()
    {
        @Override
        public Boolean run()
        {
            final ImageMetadata im = ofy().load().type(ImageMetadata.class).id(uuid.toString()).now();
            final BlobKey bk = BLOBSTORE_SERVICE.createGsBlobKey(im.getFilename().toString());
            IMAGES_SERVICE.deleteServingUrl(bk);
            ofy().delete().entity(im);
            return ImageMetadataEntityService.this.delete(uuid);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm that this is working? I am not able to delete the serving URL at all. Not by calling deleteServingUrl() or by deleting the image from GS. The URL remains active. If I overwrite the image in GS and call getServingURL() the URL returned is for the old image that does not exists anymore!!

Comment: @Jens: That sounds like a bug in App engine. I faced the same issue in python. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10774

Comment: Thanks I created another one. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11381